# Show that $\mathcal{I}$ must contain at least one positive integer.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-writing

I proved part (ii) but when I look at part(i) I feel like I have shown that when I was proving Part (2). I wanted to get some feedback on this question.

Let $\mathcal{I}$ be a non-zero ideal of $\mathbb{Z}$ (i.e. $\mathcal{I} \neq \{0\}$).

(i) Show that $\mathcal{I}$ must contain at least one positive integer.

(ii) Let $n_0$ be the least positive integer in $\mathcal{I}$. Show that $\mathcal{I}=n_0\mathbb{Z}$.

$\textbf{Proof of Part (ii):}$ From part (i), we may assume that $I$ contains at least one non-zero element $a$. We may assume that $a$ is positive, since $I$ must contain both $a$ and $-a=(-1)a$.

\null`
Consider the set $I_+$ of positive elements of $I$. This is a non-empty set of positive integers, and therefore it contains a smallest element. Let $n_0$ be the smallest element of $I_+$. We must show that $I=n_0\mathbb{Z}$:

(1) every element of $n_0\mathbb{Z}$ (every multiple of $n_0$) is in $I$

(2) every element of $I$ is in $n_0\mathbb{Z}$, i.e. is divisible by $n_0$

$\textbf{Proof of (1): }$ As $n_0$ is an element of $I$, by construction, every element $xn_0$ is in $I$, by definition of an ideal. Hence every element of $n_0\mathbb{Z}$ is in $I$.

$\textbf{Proof of (2):}$ Let $x$ be an element of $I$. We must show that $x$ is divisible by $n_0$. We may divide $x$ by $n_0$:$$x=qn_0+r \iff r=x-qn_0 \text{ where } 0\leq r <d$$ where $q$ is the quotient, and $r$ is the remainder.

Since $I$ is an ideal, which contains $n_0$ and $x$, it also contains $qn_0$ and $x-qn_0=r$. So $I$ contains $r$. Now if $r>0$, $r$ is a positive element of $I$, smaller than $n_0$, and this is a contradiction, because we chose $n_0$ as the smallest positive element of $I$.

We can conclude that $r=0$, which implies that $x$ is a multiple of $n_0$. As $x$ is any element of $I$. Hence every element of $I$ is in $n_0\mathbb{Z}$.

Hence $I=n_0\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: The second sentence of your proof of (ii) is a proof of (i), and the proof itself is fine. I suspect that (i) is there to give the student an easy starting point.

Comment: So the proof of (i) is just a one-liner?

Comment: Yep; it really is that trivial.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my intuition.

Comment: You’re welcome.